# BeautifulSoup findAll does not seem to find all

Tags: html

i'm trying to parse a website and get some info with BeautifulSoup.findAll but it doesn't find them all.. I'm using python3.5.1

the code is this

```
import urllib.request

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = ("http://www.kvk.nl/orderstraat/product-kiezen/kvknummer=547093180000&origq=brasserie+1718")
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.findAll(True):
print(tag.name)
```

The problem is as follows:
It seems tot stop "finding" at the "body" tag of the code. More specific it does not seem to find the "body" tag and all the tags that follow. When I run the code I only get the following 15 tags:

html, head, title, meta, meta, meta, meta, link, link, link, link, link, link, script, script

When I print the soup to the terminal it does seem to print the whole html and it also shows the "body" tag and everything within.

What I am specifically trying to achieve is to scrape the contents of the "h3 data-bedrijf" tag:

```
<h3 data-bedrijf='Brasserie 1718'>Brasserie 1718</h3><p class="type">Hoofdvestiging</p><p>KvK 54709318</p><p>Vestigingsnr. 000024444634</p><p>Herenweg 49</p><p>Hoogwoud</p><div class="info">
```

Unfortunately I cannot find this tag with findAll(h3)

Can anyone help? I have spent the whole afternoon and part of the evening figuring out a solution. Although the forum covers similar issues, the offered remedies have not provided the desired outcome.

Comment: Have you verified, that i actually gets the page you are expecting and not some kind of anti-ddos service like cloudfare?

Comment: Thanks over so much for the reply! I hope this answers your question: When I convert the soup tot a string and save in in a text file and open the text file in my browser the data I am trying to scrape, i.e. the content of the H3 tag is being displayed. So, yes, I think I am actually getting the page into the soup variable that I am expecting.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the file using some text editor. If there is some redirect within the file you receive, you might not notice it, if you open it in a browser.

Comment: Dear Ashish, thanks once again for your reply, I really appreciate it. I sent the soup variable to a text file and in the text file I can find the information I am trying to scrape.